# Low resolution in Debian

Tags: debian, xrandr, resolution

I installed Debian 8.3 LXDE today and I cannot adjust the resolution of my monitor. I have a 1920x1080 resolution, but allows you to install Debian to me only 1280x1024. I tried to make as here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xrandr, using xrandr to do manually, but there is no connected interfaces:

```
drahenfels@debian:~$ xrandr 
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 640 x 400, current 1280 x 1024, maximum 1280 x 1024
default connected 1280x1024+0+0 0mm x 0mm
1280x1024      0.00* 
1152x864       0.00  
1024x768       0.00  
800x600        0.00  
640x480        0.00  
720x400        0.00
```

My GPU: AMD/ATI RS780L [Radeon 3000]

Comment: check in /var/log/Xorg.0.log.  Probably the wrong driver took priority (possibly VESA).

Answer (score 0):

You probably need some non-free firmware/driver for your video card. Read https://wiki.debian.org/AtiHowTo

Answer (score 0):

Well the Arch Linux wiki is well detailed about this, so I think you've tried this...
But anyway you could manually add the mode to your system or something like that.

Example: supposing I don't have the 1920x1080 resolution down here, my display name is VGA1, and yours try to see the name on your GUI display settings manager or `arandr`, but up there on your post it says 'default connected' so I guess the name might be that, "default" (That supposition because mine says "VGA1 connected..."), I might be wrong.

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
VGA1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 510mm x 290mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   640x480       75.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

So to get the mode, I do

```
$ cvt 1920 1080
# 1920x1080 59.96 Hz (CVT 2.07M9) hsync: 67.16 kHz; pclk: 173.00 MHz
Modeline "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
$
```

Then copy all after `Modeline` to create new mode on `xrandr`

```
# xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
```

Add the newly created mode on your display

```
$ xrandr --addmode VGA1 1920x1080_60.00
```

Then apply it, you can use the GUI interface for that

```
$ xrandr -s 1920x1080_60.00
```